# Charcoal and Pastel Drawing Storage

Tags: charcoal, chalk-pastels, storage

I need to store a lot of charcoal and pastel drawings as I've recently gotten back into drawing.

I can't afford a proper solution such as a flat file at the moment.

I'm worried about stacking the drawings on top of each that can lead to possible damage on the drawings. I also don't want to leave them exposed to dust.

Is there a cheap solution that I can place between and on top of the drawings for the moment until I can afford a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would lean toward using [acid-free tissue paper](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=acid%20free%20tissue%20paper%20roll&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=31126742810&hvpos=1t2&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8990099204723022482&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_4qnhfgi1k1_b).  It comes in all sizes and you can cut out sheets large enough to separate your drawings.  I think this is similar to what my sisters use.

Of course one of the things that could help preserve them is [spray a fixative](http://drawsketch.about.com/cs/howtoindex/ht/sprayfixative.htm) on them, to help keep them from smudging.

Last if you need a physical container, there are plenty of different shaped plastic boxes, many big box stores have different options for $5-10 a piece.  Combined with the acid-free tissue paper you can store quite a few drawings in a safe location away from the elements, dust etc.

Comment: In addition to this, a few bits of masking tape around the edges of the tissue holding it in place over the drawing (preventing it sliding and smudging) can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I got you!
If you go to Walmart, or on the website, you can search for "**fixative spray**" (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00023JE7U) or this), the fixative spray I'm talking about allows you to edit, this one isn't like those expen$ive ones, this one only costs **$6**, that's actually the cheapest I have found today, I have it and I give it 5 stars, it's great! it actually prevents it from smudging and blending your charcoal or whatever you work with, the links are here: I really recommend it!

**NOTE:** you don't have to buy a fixative spray, the substitute is **hair spray**!

And finally, [this](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Krylon-Workable-Fixatif-Spray-Coating-11-oz/20683596) is the one I have!^^
I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Hi Isaac, this is again not really an answer to the question, which is "is there a cheap solution that I can place between and on top of the drawings for the moment until I can afford a better solution?". Adding fixatives will not help with storing drawings, as it only adds another variable to take into consideration. I also feel your answer contains an unnecessary amount of links: linking to a product you think is really good is okay, but I strongly suggest at least giving proper reasons for a specific linked product. Fixative is meant to prevent smudging, so that's not a unique feature :)

Comment: Also note that hair spray is a terrible long term solution, as it yellows quite easily.